# To create a transparent background for subscription box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is going a real tough to me now,
And i can't get a solution for this.
I hope many of you must have seen a site which, when you enter the site you see the homepage .. but then a transparent layer comes and shows the Subscription box with a close button above it.
Can anyone help ..
Just with the layout ..

Comment: What have you got so far? Can you paste it somewhere? No-one here will ever help you unless you at least give it a try.

Comment: Read about JQuery Colorbox,fancybox you get your answer..

Comment: Is this a pop-up with a transparent overlay preventing users from clicking on the page that you want ?

Comment: You can use for example Bootstrap modal. Example here - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: pedro ferreira, harshit tailor, virus 721 - the answer i have been looking for is on  twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals 
Thank you iwo kucharski

Comment: harshit tailor- thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Simple, its accomplished like this

```
<div class="subscribeContainer">
   subscribtion box here...
</div>
<style>
    .subscribeContainer{
       position:fixed;
       left:0;
       right:0;
       bottom:0;
       top:0;
       background:transparent;/* Default Anyway or  next line */
       background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Semi Transparent */
       display:none;/* Hidden By Default Now */
    }
</style>
```

Then you can just use jquery to fade the .subscribeContainer in like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggleSubscribeButton').on('click', function(){
       $('.subscribeContainer').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Or if you want it to fade in when the window loads, like so

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('.subscribeContainer').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: This is not tested, let me know about any mistakes

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any JavaScript just add  opacity:0.6;
For details go to the link : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp